# Is buffering time at the transmitting end included in RTT?

Tags: networking, ping

Good day!
I know this is a simple question but I can't find its answer, whenever I look for RTT, it is usually loosely defined. So, is buffering time in the transmitting node included in RTT -received by ping-?

Comment: What buffering? ICMP is an integral part of IP, so IP sends directly to the data-link protocol, which places the ICMP echo request on the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTT simply means "round-trip time." I'm not sure what "buffering" you're concerned about. The exact points of measurement depend on the exact `ping` program you're using, and there are many. For [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/), the `ping` implementation [can be found here](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/networking/ping.c). Reading it shows that the outgoing time is stamped when the outgoing ICMP packet is prepared shortly before `sendto()` is called, and the incoming time is stamped when the incoming ICMP packet is parsed shortly after `recvfrom()` is called. (Look for the calls to `monotonic_us()`.) The difference between the two is what's printed. Thus the printed value includes all time spent in the kernel's networking stack, NIC handling and so on. It also, at least for this particular implementation, includes time the `ping` process may have been waiting for a time slice. For a heavily loaded system with scheduling contention this could be significant. Other implementations may vary.

Comment: By "buffering" I mean the time that the packet spends in the device driver's buffer, that is, the FIFO queue.

Comment: @S.Toonsi OK. That time is included in the measurement and that's probably true for most/all user-space `ping` programs unless some form of [hardware timestamping](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23402/how-do-hardware-timestamps-hardstamps-work) is used as is done in [PTP](http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/). [Here](https://github.com/SLANG-foundation/SLANG/) is a ping-like program that can use hardware timestamping on compatible NICs.